# I want {{dish.name}} to be displayed in an html page.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. I've encountered a problem. I want {{dish.name}} to be displayed in html page. I've inserted it, but don't know as to why it isn't being displayed. Here is my code.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
                     content must come *after* these tags -->
                <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
                <!-- Bootstrap -->
                <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
            </head>

            <body>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-content">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">
                            {{dish.name}} <!-- I want this to be displayed -->
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <p>Put the comments here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

                app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

                    var dish={
                        name:'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label:'Hot',
                        price:'4.99',
                        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                        comments: [
                            {
                                rating:5,
                                comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                author:"John Lemon",
                                date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating:4,
                                comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                author:"Paul McVites",
                                date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating:3,
                                comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating:4,
                                comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                author:"Ringo Starry",
                                date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating:2,
                                comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                author:"25 Cent",
                                date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            }

                        ]
                    };

                    this.dish = dish;

                });

            </script>

            </body>

            </html>
```

The {{dish.name}} is located under row-content div which is located under container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgotten to use `controllerAs` pattern on `ng-controller` directive. Make alias there so that all your controller context(`this`) will exposed on view.

```
ng-controller="dishDetailController as vm"
```

Then do use `vm` before accessing any object/method from controller context.

```
{{vm.dish.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace with:

```
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

                    $scope.dish={
                        name:'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label:'Hot',
                        price:'4.99',
                        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                        comments: [
                            {
```

Basically there are two ways to achieve this:

1- Make an alias of your controller using `ng-controller="fooController as bar"` and then in your markup you use that alias (Not Recommended)

2- A much cleaner implementation would be to inject the `$scope` service in your controller and use `$scope.abc = {name:'Test'}` and in the markup you do {{abc.name}} which is termed as interpolation binding.